# JSqlparser throw exception when statement contains lateral view

Tags: sql, hiveql, jsqlparser

Goal:
To parse sql statement like :
`select id, name, lateral view explode(info) from info_table`;
Current status:
JSqlParser will throw exception:

> > ParseException:Encountered unexpected token: "lateral" "LATERAL" at line 1.

Comment: This is a known issue using JSqlParser 1.3 or 1.4 Snapshot: https://github.com/JSQLParser/JSqlParser/issues/704

Comment: @wumpz Can you fix this ?